# Prevent appointments in the same hour MySql

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, appointment

I hope you can help me figure out this little problem that I have about appointments.

Got a table called HOURS that shows the hours and the days available.

[table Hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnxXw.jpg)

And a table called APPOINTMENTS that the clients takes.

[table Appointments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1237.jpg)

Here's my select query to know which hours are available:

```
SELECT *
FROM Hours T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT T2.Hours
    FROM Appointments T2
    WHERE T2.hour = T1.hour
        AND T2.date = '17/08/2018'
)
    AND T1.days LIKE '%SAT%'
```

If I do that it will return all the hours from the table HOURS without 12:00, 12:30 which is correct.

I know how to make it not show 13:00 because the duration of the Appointment with ID 2 is 60 minutes and it's not normal interrupt an appointment to take other xD

So here's is the problem: how can I avoid showing 11:30 in case the client want take an appoinment longer than 30 mins?

Any ideas to make it directly on sql?  Or should I do it later when I put this into a table?

Comment: You should normalize your database. Using `SAT-SUN` as values will be hard to query.

Comment: Dates should be `YYYY-MM-DD` (as a DATE type) and not stored as plain text. Again; this makes it much harder to work/query with.

Comment: pleas post schema, not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add appointment `duration` to the appointment `hour`, and check that this is less than `hour` from hours.

I'd also use an anti-join pattern instead of the NOT EXISTS

Something like this:

```
SELECT h.hour
  FROM Hours h
  LEFT
  JOIN Appointments a
    ON a.date = '17/08/2018'
   AND a.hour + INTERVAL          0 MINUTE  >=  h.hour + INTERVAL  0 MINUTE
   AND a.hour + INTERVAL a.duration MINUTE  <   h.hour + INTERVAL  0 MINUTE
 WHERE a.hour IS NULL
   AND h.days LIKE '%SAT%'
```

This will return the rows from `hours` that don't overlap with an existing `appointment`.  If we want to check if there's a whole hour for an appointment, we would need to pass in 60 minutes into the query, so that we can match rows from `hours` that would overlap.